# Prove that the subset of $\ell^\infty$ defined as follows is compact

Tags: real-analysis

I have been trying to prove that the following set is compact:

Given the set

$$\left\{a_n\in\ell^\infty:|a_n|\le\frac1n\;\forall n\right\}\;,$$

where $\ell^\infty$ is the space of all bounded real sequences with the standard sup-norm as the metric, prove it is compact.

This is the first time we've seen this space, so we have no assumptions like completeness (like I've seen on a few questions here).  We have compactness iff sequentially compact iff totally bounded and complete, and not too much else.  The book we're using is Baby Rudin.

I've been stuck on this question for a while now.  First, I wanted to try proving that it was sequentially compact by constructing a convergent subsequence hopefully by picking successive terms from balls of decreasing radius, but I couldn't construct any suitable subsequence (there's no guarantee of monotonicity).

Then, I tried to do completeness by choosing an arbitrary Cauchy sequence and trying to show convergence, but I wasn't able to get anywhere with that, much less totally bounded.

The major thing that's throwing me off is the fact that this is a space of sequences, and thus we have to consider sequences of sequences, and I've been stuck on this for a while.  The other questions I've seen on here seem to use material that we don't have available to us.

Can anyone steer me onto the right track?  This doesn't seem like the type of problem where you use the definition of compactness right away.

I apologize for the lack of LaTeX, I tried looking up how to input that here, but I don't see any option in the text editor nor did it allow me to copy and paste images.

Comment: Hints: think of the sequences as "infinitely long vectors" (which they are), and use the fact (which you might need to prove) that a sequence in $\ell^{\infty}$ has a convergent subsequence if and only if the sequence has an [accumulation point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point#Types_of_limit_points). $\:$

Comment: Which should be true (yes, probably still has to be proved) since, if the set is compact, it should be closed thus it contains all of its limit points. There's also a theorem that says p is a subsequential limit iff for every \epsilon > 0 and every natural number N there exists a n >= N s.t. the ball of radius \epsilon centered at p contains p_n for infinitely many n.  This seems equivalent to what you're saying about limit points, right?

Comment: Yes, that is equivalent to the second thing I was saying. $\;$

Comment: Alright, thank you for the hint.

I'll have to try to get it down on paper now.
Choosing p=(0,0,...) wouldn't work, right?  I'm still wrapping my head around sequence of sequences. The sequence has nothing to do with the actual sequences (terms) themselves necessarily converging to 0, right?

Comment: Hint: sequential compactness

Comment: A standard method for showing a cauchy sequence converges would be to show that it converges to its pointwise limit. The point-wise limit can be shown to exist by elementary analytic methods, such as the compactness of $[-1/n,1/n]$.